# Shopify Product&Collection Export Automation

Tags: shopify, feed, shopify-app

I would like to discuss with you about a solution for an issue I`m having.
I have a marketplace, I want to allow Shopify sellers to sell on my marketplace.

I`m looking for the best solution to export the Shopify sellers products & Collections in a feed. I want to make this whole process to be automatic as possible. I dont want the sellers to have to deal with all the technical stuff.

Also, a feature the solution must contain is - I need to map the field once, to map the Shopify categories to my marketplace categories.

Do you know any solution, app or something that can help me?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming. One of the other SE sites should be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

For making your system automatic you can take reference about shopify webhooks [Shopify webhooks](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#top)

and you can take reference regarding  [listed public app marketplace solution on shopify](https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=marketplace)